# Compile-time computation (C++ v. C)

Tags: c++, c, metaprogramming, constexpr, compile-time

I understand that the `constexpr` keyword can be used to perform compile-time computation in C++. For example:

```
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1));
}
```

(taken from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Can compile-time computation be considered a key advantage of C++ v. C ?

As I understand, compile-time computation is not possible in C. `constexpr` is not available, and the code would have to be evaluated at runtime I believe.

Is this this one manner in which a C++ programs can achieve better performance (e.g. speed) versus an equivalent C program ?

Comment: The absence of `constexpr` or `consteval` does not mean that the compiler can’t do the computation at compile time if all values are known. With the keyword you tell the compiler what the intent is, so that the compiler can warm you about a mistake you made to ensure your intent.

Comment: Fun fact: the presence of `constexpr` doesn't guarantee compile-time computation, either.

Comment: Sure, I agree that compile-time evaluation can happen without the `constexpr`. 

Also, I agree that the keyword does not mean compile-time evaluation in all cases. However, as far as I am aware, it does guaruntee compile-time evaluation when the declared function is called with constant expression arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one thing is certain - compile-time computation makes C++ compilers **necessarily more complicated** and the **compilation speed** will **necessarily be slower**, because a compiler is required to do it during compilation time; see for example

```
constexpr int factorial(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1));
}

int main(void) {
    static_assert(factorial(10) == 3628800, "factorial 10 was correct");
    static_assert(factorial(3) == 42, "factorial 3 was 42");
}
```

Which must fail to *compile* because of the *latter* `static_assert` but not the former.

---

A C compiler does not require such complexity because there is no requirement that a C compiler must be able to calculate the value of a recursive function during compilation time. A simple C compiler can very well assemble each *statement* to machine code separately without having to remember what the previous statements did. The C standard certainly does not require it to be able to evaluate recursive functions during compilation time.

But it is not to say that no C compiler would do that during compilation. See this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", factorial(10));
}
```

[Compiled with GCC 10.2 as a *C program* with -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/Ya4Gzo), and thanks to [the *as-if* rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/918959), the program became

```
factorial:
        mov     eax, 1
        cmp     edi, 1
        jle     .L4
.L3:
        mov     edx, edi
        sub     edi, 1
        imul    eax, edx
        cmp     edi, 1
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 3628800
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

which more directly corresponds to

```
unsigned factorial(unsigned n) {
     unsigned i = 1;
     while (n > 1) {
         i *= n;
         n --;
     }
     return i;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", 3628800);
}
```

i.e. the compiler not only flattened the recursion to a simple `while` loop but also resolved the factorial of the constant, and all without any special keywords.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see that the "as-if" rule allows the compiler to deduce values under certain conditions.

However, if we look only at what is required to be supported by a compiler for either language, can we say that C++ has an advantage here ? 

For example, all C++17 compilers must support compile-time computation with `constexpr`. However, this is not guaranteed in any form by the C language itself. Therefore, as you have shown some C compilers will have this capability with high optimization, and some won't. But with C++ it is a guarantee.

Comment: @thatmarkdude: if you are looking for opinions about which is *better* between C and C++, you are barking the wrong tree... and off topic too. The only guarantee you get is C++ is **vastly** more complex than C to say the least. This complexity comes with some advantages and some costs too. Try comparing Formula 1 racing and tractor pulling and determine which is more powerful...

Comment: @thatmarkdude Yes, I think all C++ developers will agree with that, and all C developers disagree (shouldn't you know what you're doing when writing code and also know how it will be compiled?:). That's the thing about comparing languages, it's a matter of opinion...

Comment: The problem with C++ as I see it is that people discover that the template system and compile time evaluation were not yet *powerful enough* and they add something way more complicated to it in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

> Can compile-time computation be considered a key advantage of C++ v. C ?

### Actually, what is important is not compilation, but [software building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build).

Refer to Wikipedia page on [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation).

Then, be aware that **many software projects** (including many open source projects on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)) **are *generating* C** (or even C++) **code from something more abstract** (e.g. using software tools). A typical example is obviously parser generators (a.k.a. [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler)) like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/). Another example are glue code generators like `rpcgen` or [SWIG](https://swig.org/). And [GNU autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) adapt your build to the software packages available on your computer. Notice that both [Chicken-Scheme](http://call-cc.org/) and [Bigoo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/) are generating C code from [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) source code. See of course [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065). In some cases huge C files are produced from tiny input (see also the [XBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) format). [Maple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) is able to generate large C files, and there are cases where generating a lot of C code -e.g. half a million lines- makes sense (as explained in Pitrat's book [*Artificial beings: the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015)) and [blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/).

At last, [whole-program optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/370237/40065) can exist (see the `-flto` flag in recent GCC for [Link-Time-Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html); you practically would compile and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) with `gcc -Wall -O2 -flto`) and requires some compiler support at "link-time".

**In some situations,** the compile time is not that important (think of e.g. compiling [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) or the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) or [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/) from its source code base), but **the build time can last hours, or certainly dozens of minutes** (because a lot of different [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) - concretely `*.c` or `*.cc` files - have to be compiled then linked).

Google is rumored to consume hours of computer time internally to build most of their internal software.

**Notice that the first C++ compilers** (e.g. [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront)) **have been implemented as C code generators**, and that a large software such as the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has *dozens* of specialized C or C++ code generators. Try to build on your laptop from the available source code a GCC cross-compiler targeting your [RaspBerryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/) board (which is too small and underpowered to straight-compile GCC on it). Build instructions on [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromsratch.org/) are then relevant.

For an example of a C program generating C code, see my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) code for Linux, or my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) program described in [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report. Past versions of the obsolete [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project did generate a million lines of C or C++ code. `manydl.c` is able to generate then compile C code during days, and illustrates that [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) can be used many times. For an example of a C++ software generating C++ on Linux, see my [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project. Look also into [tunes.org](https://tunes.org/) for discussions related to metaprogramming and generation of C or C++ code.

#### Consider also [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) situations

e.g. compiling C code for an [Arduino](https://arduino.cc), or C++ code for your [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)  on your laptop, perhaps with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Or compiling on your PC code for a distant [top500](https://top500.org/) supercomputer.

### regarding C++ [versus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versus) C

**My understanding of the C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) is that compile-time computation is not specified there** (but I don't claim to be a C++ expert).
In particular, **nothing forbids you to make your C++ [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing))** (you could code that in C, in C++, in Ocaml, in Java, etc...). Consider that idea as an interesting programming exercise (but read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) before trying).

My opinion is that a classroom of students learning C++ could be considered as a C++ implementation, as specified in that C++ standard. A good way of teaching C++ is to ask the classroom about the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of several C++ programs, and that can be taught with pencil and paper or a [whiteboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteboard). I actually taught a course on [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) that way (at Paris 6 University).
The board was black, and I used chalks of various colors.

Look also into software tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Both are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), so you could study their source.

> Is this this one manner in which a C++ programs can achieve better performance (e.g. speed) versus an equivalent C program ?

That it your opinion, and **I disagree**. What make you think that the runtime of [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) or of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) would be faster (you should download and study the source code) if it has been written in C++ ? **An interesting exercise could be to recode in C++ the [tinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) compiler** (for C, targeting x86 32 bits and x86-64 bits on Linux, coded in C), and benchmark any improvement. That simple but clever compiler is compiling C code very quickly, but make too few [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

Comment: I think you're missing the key point in the question, which is the **v.**

Comment: What do you mean? Which `v` ? I am reading it as [versus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versus). I did study Latin, but English is *not* my mother tongue.

Comment: Well, yes, versus, the question was more like "is it an advantage of C++ over C that it calculate things at compilation time?"

Comment: Such a thorough and documented answer! Yet not exactly addressing the question, which seems off topic anyway. Sorry I cannot UV more than once :)